# CNC Manufacturability Analysis Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to build a CNC manufacturability analysis app using Autodesk Forge.
Setting the computational geometry algorithms aside, what kind of geometrical data can I extract from CAD files using this platform? also, is there an existing app I am unaware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the input file format you can convert to different other formats:
[Supported Translations](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/)

Though it's not obvious from the above list, all input formats support conversion to OBJ format, which can also be done at subcomponent level - so you don't have to export the whole model to OBJ.

Here is a sample that lets you access your files from A360 and convert them into whatever format is currently supported for them:
[Model Derivative API sample](https://derivatives.autodesk.io)

Source code: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-nodejs-sample